# Need help to use Swedish letters

Tags: python, html, jupyter

Student programmer in Python. I need to include Swedish letters in my HTML-tag but the output shows non-readable characters. My goal is by using libs like `folium` and `iPython.display` , I can apply the Swedish name within the HTML tag. It's hard to explain so I'll just show you what I got so far:

```
import geopandas
import folium    
from IPython.core.display import HTML

    HTML("""
    <style>
    #top {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>
    """)

    '<a href="https://www.google.se/maps/place/Stapelb%C3%A4ddsparken+Skatepark/@55.6135451,12.9816805,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4653a5ed00b7ea67:0x53c9bf8f0eae32d8!8m2!3d55.6135451!4d12.9838693" target="_blank" content="text/html" > Stapelbäddsparken </a>'
```

So I need "Stapelbäddsparken" to be read but my output is "StapelbÃ¤ddsparken". When I search for an answer I only find solutions that are 7 years old or older, I tried their soulutions but without results..

I am using jupyter notebook, but testing in google colab (if it matters). What I'm looking for is either a lib to import the usage for Swedish letters, a way to include python variables inside the a-tag or if you know any other way. Thanks for all the effort on before hand!

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: No Python 3, sorry for not writing that earlier

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I found "https://www.html.am/reference/html-special-characters.cfm" and by entering the characters code, I was able to imply whichever character I was looking for. No need to import a specific lib or anything.

Example: Swedish 'ä' = `&auml;` . So 'Stapelbäddsparken' = `Stapelb&auml;ddsparken` in HTML.

I hope this will be helpful to others as well.